# Sync user meta data to a second database

Tags: database, sync

I need to sync data from the wp_users and usermeta databases to a second table upon registration. I have accomplished the wp_user part successfuly by placing the following code in my functions file:

````
function add_to_YjT_bookly_customers($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
    $wpdb->insert( 'YjT_bookly_customers', array('full_name' => $user_info->user_login,'wp_user_id' => $user_info->ID,'email' =>$user_info->user_email,'first_name' => $user_info->first_name), array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_YjT_bookly_customers');```
````

But I also want to sync data from the usermeta db, specifically the first_name and last_name. You can see from the code above that the target db is Yjt_bookly_customers and that I tried (hoped) that the first_name would also sync. And while the user_login, id, and pw sync'ed, the first_name did not. I guess the metadata is not covered by the $user_id variable or I am simply not accessing it correctly. So my question is what code would I need to add to also sync the first_name, last_name fields from the usermeta table to successfully sync those as well at registration submission.